# Benq GW2480 Gnome controls not working

Tags: gnome, brightness, monitor, volume-control

I've a problem with a new Benq GW2480.

I've just plugged it in with a hdmi to usb-c cable to my Intel nuc 8i5. It found it immediately. But I cannot control the brightness or volume, the Gnome controls are there but have no effect.

My old Benq (GL2450) worked fine with Ubuntu 20.04.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Best

Comment: experiencing the same issue on my laptop using gnome 3.38.2 and Mesa Intel. The fn + brightness keys don't work either

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's down to the 'adaptive technology', making brightness settings in many newer monitors redundant.

Many monitor and TV models no longer have a brightness setting because for HDR or eyecare to work properly peak brightness must be maintained, meaning the brightness slider serves no useful purpose. If you lower the brightness while in HDR, you’ll just ruin the image quality and defeat the whole logic of having an HDR-capable display.

In this particular BenQ the Brightness Intelligence sensor monitors ambient light in your environment and actively adjusts screen brightness for the most comfortable viewing experience. So there is no way to overide this, other than to choose one of the 'settings in the monitor's menu.

I've actually found I don't need the old brightness adjust button, it does indeed seem to adapt intelligently to the ambient light.